# Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API' while adding additional disk on a VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-api

After adding additional disk on a VM instance, I got a "Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API'" error when clicking save.

[image]

Does anybody know what causes this error and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you just added additional disk to your VM and tried to save the changes or did you modified it in some other way too ? The more details you share the better it will be to troubleshoot you issue.

Comment: I just used "+ Add new disk" (60GB) to my whole new VM and then saved the changes without doing or modifying anything else.
GCP kept showing the same error message (Required...) after I clicked "Save" every time I tried.

However, I could manually create a new disk first and then use "+ Attach existing disk" to the same VM instance with no problem.
It's weird that I was able to attach an existing (also new) disk but not able to add a new one to the same VM.

Comment: I'm getting the same error all of a sudden, and @JuliaChang's suggestion was the right fix for me.

Comment: @JuliaChang - did you create this VM "by hand" or it was created by [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs) as a part of cluster or  a  group ?

Comment: I created the VM through GCP console> Compute Engine> VM Instances> CREATE INSTANCE

Comment: Can you run `$ gcloud compute instances describe bugdata-node-1` in cloud shell and edit & paste the output of the command into your question ?

Comment: There's was a typo in my comment - instead of `bugdata....` there should be `bigdata...` - it's your instance name. You run commands from [Cloud Shell](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?cloudshell=true).

Comment: You're trying to run the command from the inside if the VM, please run it from [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell).

Comment: I attached (not added) the big data-node-1-disk-1 by creating it manually first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're experiencing is a bug. I've found [this thread on Google Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/163110720) - it looks like Google Engineers already know about it and working on solving it - you can add your email to a CC list or post description of your case there.

If you do this you will be updated as soon as the fix will be rolled out to production.

Comment: Google has already fixed the bug. I am currently able to add a new disk by editing VM. (no need to create a disk first and then attach it)